# CSS child selector not working - all decendants of the type affected

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am building a menu with nested lists. I used a child selector (`#menu-novo li:hover > ul`) in order to show/hide only immediate decendents, but it still shows all of them. Any help with this?

```css
#menu-novo-container {
  font-family: tahoma, Arial, helvetica, Serif;   
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#menu-novo {
 border: 3px solid green;
}

.menu-novo-item {
  border: 3px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-novo-link {
  border: 3px solid yellow;
}

.menu-novo-submenu {
  border: 3px solid red;
  display: none;
}

#menu-novo li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

.menu-novo-link {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-novo-container">
    <ul id="menu-novo">
        <li class="menu-novo-item"> 1
            <ul class="menu-novo-submenu">
            <li class="menu-novo-item"><a href="#" class="menu-novo-link">1.1</a></li>
            <li class="menu-novo-item"><a href="#" class="menu-novo-link">1.2</a></li>
            <li class="menu-novo-item"><a href="#" class="menu-novo-link">1.3</a></li>
            <li class="menu-novo-item">1.4
                <ul class="menu-novo-sumbenu">
                    <li class="menu-novo-item"><a href="#" class="menu-novo-link">1.4.1</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-novo-item"><a href="#" class="menu-novo-link">1.4.2</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-novo-item"><a href="#" class="menu-novo-link">1.4.3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>               
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**I guess this will receive a ton of downvotes because it has been asked already, but other posts don't help my case and I'm getting desperate here :)**

Comment: Please include your code within the question.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, you first need to set `display: none` for second level `ul` and then `display: block` on hover of second level `li`

```
#menu-novo li ul li ul {
   display: none;
}

#menu-novo li ul li:hover ul{
   display: block;
}
```

```css
#menu-novo-container {
  font-family: tahoma, Arial, helvetica, Serif;   
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#menu-novo {
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.menu-novo-item {
  border: 3px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-novo-link {
  border: 3px solid yellow;
}

.menu-novo-submenu {
  border: 3px solid red;
  display: none;
}

#menu-novo li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

.menu-novo-link {
  display: block;
}
#menu-novo li ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

#menu-novo li ul li:hover ul{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-novo-container">
    <ul id="menu-novo">
        <li class="menu-novo-item"> 1
            <ul class="menu-novo-submenu">
            <li class="menu-novo-item"><a href="#" class="menu-novo-link">1.1</a></li>
            <li class="menu-novo-item"><a href="#" class="menu-novo-link">1.2</a></li>
            <li class="menu-novo-item"><a href="#" class="menu-novo-link">1.3</a></li>
            <li class="menu-novo-item">1.4
                <ul class="menu-novo-sumbenu">
                    <li class="menu-novo-item"><a href="#" class="menu-novo-link">1.4.1</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-novo-item"><a href="#" class="menu-novo-link">1.4.2</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-novo-item"><a href="#" class="menu-novo-link">1.4.3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>               
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Please do not link to 3rd party sites as those links can become dead over time. Just post a code snippet in your answer.

Comment: Sorry @ScottMarcus actually the question had the third party link in it so I updated the code there itself. By the way your advice really makes sense. +1 for that.

Comment: @RajanBenipuri Thanks for the answer. But could I make it work for any level of nesting? With your code, if I'm right, only first and the second level would work.

Comment: Yes it will work with any level of nesting but if you have multiple level of nesting its better to assign a class name for them.

Comment: @RajanBenipuri your code works for the first and the second level, not for the third. So, it doesn't work for any level. I couldn't have a menu 4 levels deep and have this work. Does that mean that I have to manually target each submenu, either via classes or `li ul li ul ... li ul` method? If that is the case, your advice on classes makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You have added same classes for nested `li` and `ul`, so that add different classes for that

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left:0;
}
#menu-novo-container {
  font-family: tahoma, Arial, helvetica, Serif;   
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#menu-novo {
  border: 3px solid green;
}
.menu-novo-item {
  border: 3px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu-novo-link {
  border: 3px solid yellow;
}
.menu-novo-submenu {
  border: 3px solid red;  
}
.menu-novo-submenu.child1,
#menu-novo > li:hover > ul.child1 li .child2 {
  display:none;
}
#menu-novo > li:hover > ul.child1,
#menu-novo > li:hover > ul.child1 li:hover .child2 {
  display: block;
}
.menu-novo-link {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-novo-container">
  <ul id="menu-novo">
    <li class="menu-novo-item"> 1
      <ul class="menu-novo-submenu child1">
        <li class="menu-novo-item"><a href="#" class="menu-novo-link">1.1</a></li>
        <li class="menu-novo-item"><a href="#" class="menu-novo-link">1.2</a></li>
        <li class="menu-novo-item"><a href="#" class="menu-novo-link">1.3</a></li>
        <li class="menu-novo-item">1.4
          <ul class="menu-novo-sumbenu child2">
            <li class="menu-novo-item"><a href="#" class="menu-novo-link">1.4.1</a></li>
            <li class="menu-novo-item"><a href="#" class="menu-novo-link">1.4.2</a></li>
            <li class="menu-novo-item"><a href="#" class="menu-novo-link">1.4.3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>               
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm looking for a solution that would work with any level of nesting. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

```css
#menu-novo-container {
  font-family: tahoma, Arial, helvetica, Serif;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#menu-novo {
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.menu-novo-item {
  border: 3px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-novo-link {
  border: 3px solid yellow;
}

#menu-novo li>ul {
  border: 3px solid red;
  display: none;
}

#menu-novo li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

.menu-novo-link {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Its showing all of ul because you have not hide (display: none;) for children ul.
So add below missing css and should work:

```
#menu-novo li ul {
    display:none;
}

#menu-novo li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I did.

Comment: I have updated your css and it works. Your css does not work because it has display none with class name ".menu-novo-submenu" and with li:hover > ul using display:block will do for all ul by overriding your ".menu-novo-submenu" property. So, it would be better to follow the parent-child rules precisely. Hope it helps.